# Join two datasets by using the first column in scala spark

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark

I have two data sets like,
(film name, actress's name) and
(film name, director's name)

I want to join them by using the name of the film, so (film name, actress's name, director's name).

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

import scala.io.Source

object spark {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("FindFrequentPairs").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val text1: RDD[String] = sc.textFile(args(0))
    val text2: RDD[String] = sc.textFile(args(1))

    val joined = text1.join(text2)
```

I tried to use 'join' but it says 'cannot resolve symbol join.'
Do you have any idea how to join them?

This is part of my datasets, (filme name, actress).

```
('"Please Like Me" (2013) {Rhubarb and Custard (#1.1)}', '$haniqua')
('"Please Like Me" (2013) {Spanish Eggs (#1.5)}', '$haniqua')
('A Woman of Distinction (1950)  (uncredited)', '& Ashour, Lucienne')
('Around the World (1943)  (uncredited)', '& Ashour, Lucienne')
('Chain Lightning (1950)  (uncredited)', '& Ashour, Lucienne')
```

Comment: Your datasets both are `RDD[String]`... you will need them to at least be in the form `RDD[(String, String)]`.

Comment: But if I use RDD[(String, String)], it says 'expressions of RDD[String] doesn't conform to expected type RDD[(String, String)]. Then, should I transform the text file?

Comment: Of course it will! I just meant you will have to do some work to transform you dataset to the right form. Are the strings in the datasets of the form `"(<some-name1>, <some-name2>)"`?

Comment: Yes, each data set has two elements like that. To me, it already seems to have the form of (string, string), so I have no idea how to transform them. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @Alec For example, one of (film name, actress) is '('"Variety" (1936) {(1937-06-05)}', '& Ashour, Lucienne')'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create pairRDDs first for your data sets then you have to apply join transformation. Your data sets are not looking accurate.

Please consider the below example.

```
**Dataset1**

a 1
b 2
c 3

**Dataset2**

a 8
b 4
```

Your code should be like below in Scala

```
val pairRDD1 = sc.textFile("/path_to_yourfile/first.txt").map(line => (line.split(" ")(0),line.split(" ")(1)))

val pairRDD2 = sc.textFile("/path_to_yourfile/second.txt").map(line => (line.split(" ")(0),line.split(" ")(1)))

val joinRDD = pairRDD1.join(pairRDD2)

joinRDD.collect
```

Here is the result from scala shell

```
res10: Array[(String, (String, String))] = Array((a,(1,8)), (b,(2,4)))
```

Comment: I edited my question and added my datasets. Can you check once more? The way you showed didn't work..

Comment: Also, I tried to split them using ',' but there are too many commas so it's impossible to split data using comma.

Comment: your data set is not in consistent format , you have to clean and format your data first

Comment: If you see carefully, each line in the file is already a 2-tuple. Should I still need to clean the data?

Comment: as per your code , it looks like you are trying to load data from text File , is that data in tuple format in your text file ?

Comment: yes, all of the data is in tuple format, even though they look messy.

Comment: your data is not in valid tuple format , please check in scala , if it is string it should be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124758/discussion-between-tobby-and-arunakiran-nulu).